# Post list of list of model object to Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Form like this

[image]

**ViewModel:**

```cs
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SizeColorQuantityViewModel> SizeColorQuantities { get; set; }
}
public class SizeColorQuantityViewModel
{
    public string ColorId { get; set; }
    public List<SizeAndQuantity> SizeAndQuantities { get; set; }
}
public class SizeAndQuantity
{
    public int SizeId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```cs
@model ProjectSem3.Areas.Admin.Models.ProductViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    string[] ListColor = { "Red", "Blue" };
    string[] ListSize = { "S", "M", "L", "XL" };
}
    @for (var i = 0; i < ListColor.Length; i++)
    {
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Color:</label>
       <div class="col-md-2">
          @Html.TextBox("[" + i + "].ColorId", null, new { @Value = ListColor[i], @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Size and Quantity:</label>
       @for (var j = 0; j < ListSize.Length; j++)
       {
       <div class="col-md-2">
          @Html.TextBox("[" + i + "][" + j + "].SizeAndQuantities.SizeId", null, new
          {
          @class = "form-control",
          @style = "margin-bottom: 15px",
          @Value = ListSize[j],
          @readonly = "readonly"
          })
          @Html.TextBox("[" + i + "][" + j + "].SizeAndQuantities.Quantity", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
       </div>
       }
    </div>
    }
```

**Controller:**

```cs
// GET: Admin/Product
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
// POST: Admin/Product
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductViewModel product, IEnumerable
<SizeColorQuantityViewModel>
sizeColorQuantity, IEnumerable
<SizeAndQuantity>
sizeAndQuantity)
{ 
     return View();
}
```

I can get value which is passed from ViewModel `IEnumerable<SizeColorQuantityViewModel> sizeColorQuantity` to Controller. But with this model `IEnumerable<SizeAndQuantity> sizeAndQuantity`, I can't get any value.
Cause this is 2-D Array so, I have no idea for this issues. Could you teach me how to bind value for `IEnumerable<SizeAndQuantity> sizeAndQuantity.`

Comment: Your generating inputs with name attributes that do not relate to your model, but not a lot of this code is making sense. Why do you have collections `ListColor` and `ListSize` in your view? Are you trying to edit the quantity for a product with Red/Small, and Red/Medium and Red/Large etc, and the same again for Blue/Small, Blue/Medium etc?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, I also think a lot of ways to post a Product with Size, Color and Quantity. Have you any another ways? If you don't mind, could you explan me more? Thanks a lot :D

Comment: You need to make a lot of changes to make this work. Can you change `IEnumerable<SizeColorQuantityViewModel>` to `List<SizeColorQuantityViewModel>`? (it will make it easier)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I follow this tips: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/855577/List-of-Model-Object-Post-to-Controller-in-ASP-NET

Before, I also set List<SizeColorQuantityViewModel>  but It seems to not be working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your generating inputs with name attributes that have no relationship to your model, therefore cannot be bound by the `DefaultModelBinder`. You need to start by generating the data in the controller (not in the view) so that you can bind to your model.

The following assumes you change your `SizeColorQuantities` property to `List<SizeColorQuantityViewModel>`

```cs
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var colors = new List<string>(){ "Red", "Blue" };
    var sizes = new List<string>(){ "S", "M", "L", "XL" };

    var model = new ProductViewModel()
    {
        Product = "My product",
        SizeColorQuantities = new List<SizeColorQuantityViewModel>
    };
    foreach(var color in colors)
    {
        var child = new SizeColorQuantityViewModel()
        {
            ColorId = color,
            SizeAndQuantities = new List<SizeAndQuantity>
        };
        model.SizeColorQuantities.Add(child);
        foreach(var size in sizes)
        {
            child.SizeAndQuantities.Add(new SizeAndQuantity()
            {
                SizeId = size // assumes SizeId is changed to string, not int
            });
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

You now have a correctly populated view model that will be passed to the view which you can bind to with strongly typed `HtmlHelpers` inside nested `for` loops

```cs
@model ProductViewModel
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ....
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.SizeColorQuantities.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SizeColorQuantities[i].ColorId, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
        for (int j = 0; j < Model.SizeColorQuantities[i].SizeAndQuantities .Count; j++)
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SizeColorQuantities[i].SizeAndQuantities[j].SizeId, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SizeColorQuantities[i].SizeAndQuantities[j].Quantity, new { @class = "form-control" })
        }
    }
    <input type="submit" ... />
}
```

Note: **Always** use the strongly typed `***For()` `HtmlHelper` methods and **never** attempt to set the `value` (or `name`) attribute when using a `HtmlHelper` method.

Your POST method now needs to be

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductViewModel model)
{
    ....
}
```

Note you can also use custom `EditorTemplate`'s for your types as explained in [HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943), which also explains how your `name` attributes must be generated in order to bind to collections. In your case, for example your `Quantity` inputs need to be (compare that to what your currently generating)

```cs
<input name="SizeColorQuantities[0].SizeAndQuantities[0].Quantity" ... />
<input name="SizeColorQuantities[0].SizeAndQuantities[1].Quantity" ... />
....
<input name="SizeColorQuantities[1].SizeAndQuantities[0].Quantity" ... />
<input name="SizeColorQuantities[1].SizeAndQuantities[1].Quantity" ... />
....
```

Comment: Could I ask you one more question? I release that model return from HttpPost is null. Do you have some idea?

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductViewModel model)
        {
            var test = product.Product;
            return View();
        }

Comment: Sorry @Stephen Muecke. I find out how to resolve this problem. Cause I set params variable is "product", it's same name with properties name. 
Thanks you a lot.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35889181/4642316