# Adding, Editing a list in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i have a real dumbquestion... i cannot find an answer to and im kinda ashamed to ask...
I have a class called Menu with 3 properties (not counting sql id),
A string with name
A float with price
and a List Ingrediants

i can get and add/edit the name and price in the MVC view no problem... but my issues begin with the List... how do you go about adding it? Ive been searching for 2 days now, and i cannot find an answer... it is possible i am using the wrong keywords for this issue though i dont know which ones would be correct.

I also want to apologize in advance if this question insults your intelligence.... no need to berate me, already did that enough

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129555/add-item-into-list-from-view-and-pass-to-controller-in-mvc5

Comment: "how do you go about adding it? Ive been searching for 2 days now, and i cannot find an answer... it is possible i am using the wrong keywords for this issue though i dont know which ones would be correct." What do you mean here? What are you trying to achieve and got stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

> My issues begin with the List... how do you go about adding it?

Well, based on your scenario and requirement, in order to add list of `Ingredients` while creating menu, you should execute loop on Ingredients index.

While adding new Ingredients, you should have a table with html Id attribute. So there would be a button on the button click event, you should append new Items or rows inside the table. Finally, bind it with the model and submit to the controller.

Let's have a look how we could achieve that.

Model:

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Menu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal  Price { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new Menu { Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>() }); 
}
```

View:

```
@model Menu

@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
    int i = 0; 
}

<h1>Create Menu</h1>

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="Name" value="@Model.Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price:</label>
        <input type="number" id="price" name="Price" value="@Model.Price" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <h2>Ingredients</h2>
    <table id="ingredientsTable" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var ingredient in Model.Ingredients)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="Ingredients[@i].Id" value="@ingredient.Id" />
                        <input type="text" name="Ingredients[@i].Name" value="@ingredient.Name" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger removeIngredient" data-id="@ingredient.Id">Remove</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                i++; 
            }

          
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Ingredients[@i].Id" value="0" /> 
                    <input type="text" name="Ingredients[@i].Name" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger removeIngredient">Remove</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addIngredient">Add Ingredient</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".addIngredient").click(function () {
                var table = $("#ingredientsTable");
                var row = "<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='Ingredients[new][@i].Id' value='0' />" + 
                    "<input type='text' name='Ingredients[new][@i].Name' class='form-control' /></td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger removeIngredient'>Remove</button></td></tr>";
                table.find("tbody").append(row);
            });

            $(".removeIngredient").click(function () {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** This could a good start for you. If you encounter any issue, please post a new question with sufficient information along with reproducible code snippet.

Comment: Thank you for this post, this is exactly what i was having trouble with :))

I will be be trying to understand exactly what is happening, but this is a great start. Though i am curious if your remove button is also broken. If not then i have some digging to do to try and figure out why mine is not working properly xD

Once again thank you for your assistance :))

Comment: Thanks for your response and the delete button is also functional. Let's give a try.

Comment: Very interesting. The remove button for me works the first time, but it will not work any other time after the first...

Comment: Actually, I didn't consider all the logic or test case, the main point was to show how we can implement that, if  have any specific requirement, I would suggest you to post new question with the code snippet and description details. So that I it can be checked.

Comment: Ok, ill first try and figure it out myself. and if i cannot find a solution i will post a new question.